# white background problem in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Open up this site in IE8:

http://www.bavarianblue.com

See the white background? Any ideas what is causing that? I tried assigning a clear gif to it, and nothing changed. Works great in Chrome and FF

[image]

Help please : )

Comment: First suggestion would be to polish your markup. Currently the W3C Validator is showing a handful of errors : http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//bavarianblue.com/ - and IE8 is notorious for getting upset when it is not getting compliant code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the Developer Tools in IE8 (Keyboard shortcut F12) and inspect the element with the white background you will notice the following inline style applied to the element:

```
<div class="slide" style="z-index: 5; position: absolute; background-color: #ffffff; zoom: 1; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px;" cycleH="277" cycleW="500" jQuery1285163831375="11">
```

What is generating the HTML for you? I assume it's JQuery UI?

Comment: Not sure... it's a WP theme that I am hacking the heck out, whoever originally wrote it took some shortcuts. This should be me down the right path

Comment: Found the problem - it was in the JS. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

In IE the `<div class="slide">` gets a `style="background-color:#fff;"`. This is a fix for IE to make the fade transition text smooth and not jagged. Find where the color is being set and replace it with your bg color (probably in the .js or where you call the slide plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated and come to a solution

```
#spotlight .slide{
 background: url("images/featured_bg.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `<div class="slide">` set the background-color: Transparent

Answer (score 0):

the first `div` in `#spotlight` has a `backgound-color:#ffffff;` set as inline-style (which can easily be seen by using the developer-tool (F12)) - remove that and you'll get what you expect.

Comment: Don't remove that since the transition effect will look crap in IE - just change the color to what it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Little later but something that worked for me dealing with IE8 background issues:

```
selector{
    background: transparent;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)" !important; /* IE8 */   
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF) !important;   /* IE6 & 7 */      
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Make sure to adjust the filter hex color if you want a color (remove the "00" if you are not wanting a transparent result